# DatagridView displaying error when connected with filing

Tags: c#, datagridview, read-write

[image: the GUI i am working with]
problem occurs while `filing` it is saving data amazingly and on retrieving the records on `DataGridView` here is the code i am trying but it is also showing the `Last Value` of column and `1st value` of next column like this is the info in file and data from file is like: [image: Why same data always??]

```
3519,laiba,99

3519,maheen,89
```

here is my code:

```
 private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream("D://abc.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(f);
            sw.Write(txtregno.Text+","+txtname.Text+","+txtmarks.Text+";");
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
            sw.Close();
        }

        private void btnshow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream("D://abc.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f);
            string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lineWiseRecord = data.Split(';');
            foreach (string item in lineWiseRecord)
            {
                string[] colWiseRecord = item.Split(','); 
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(colWiseRecord[0], colWiseRecord[1], colWiseRecord[2] );
            }
            f.Close();
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the runtime value of `data`, exactly as it exists? Do not format it in any way.

Comment: So comma separated values and semicolon separated entries. Why are you writing everything in a single line? Use the `sw.WriteLine` method to write a single entry/row per line. Use the `sr.ReadLine` method in a loop to read and insert them into the DGV.

Comment: There MUST be something else going on. In its current state, the posted code could not possibly run to completion. Example: if `txtregno.Text` = 3519, `txtname.Text` = laiba and  `txtmarks.Text` = 99… then, if you click `button1` three (3) times, then you will end up with a file that contains… `3519,laiba,99;3519,laiba,99;3519,laiba,99;` … (note the last `;`) this appears to be what you want even though breaking each “;” into lines would be a better approach.

Comment: Given this text is in the file `abc.txt`, then, when the user clicks `button2` … they are going to be presented with an index out of range exception. The posted pictures of the three rows can NOT be coming from THIS code. The exception is going to come from the line… `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(colWiseRecord[0], colWiseRecord[1], colWiseRecord[2]);` … and the reason being that `colWiseRecord` will be “empty” on the last iteration of the `foreach (string item in lineWiseRecord) {…` loop.

Comment: The command `string[] lineWiseRecord = data.Split(';');` is going to return FOUR (4) elements, such that the last element will be empty given the last ‘;’ noted earlier. Therefore, when the foreach loop gets to the last element in `lineWiseRecord` and executes the line `string[] colWiseRecord = item.Split(',');` ,… then, `colWiseRecord` will be an “empty” array. This is going to throw the exception on the first… `colWiseRecord[0]` reference. Without checking for this empty or smaller array, index exceptions are bound to happen.

Comment: Lastly, after adding a check for an empty or smaller array, the posted code appears to work as expected. As I started… there MUST be something else going on that you are not showing.

Comment: @JohnG i want it to show all records in file only with three arguments ..

Comment: I do not know what you mean by _”only with three arguments “_ ? Using the code in the `button1` click event, there are only three (3) fields for each record. I am getting the impression the data you are getting is not what you think it is. My comments are using the posted code, and I am betting you are either running different code that what is posted or different data. If you fix the error I described earlier, then from what I can see the code works as expected.

Comment: @JohnG the comment of yours i marked above" is the issue i am having is i dont want it to show '''3519'''  in the marks column

Comment: As I stated previously, when I run the posted code, it did NOT show the extra “3519” in the marks column. Also, I cannot stress how important it is to post the current most updated code that you are using. When you show the picture with the extra “3519” and you post the code to reproduce the picture, then something is wrong. As I said before, the posted code could NOT possibly produce what the picture shows. You should update your code to produce the extra “3519.”

Comment: @JohnG array out of bound .. why is it showing this exception now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217676/discussion-between-ashiq-pervez-and-johng).

Comment: Look at my previous comments... the error is clear... in addition, surrounding this in a try catch to swallow/ignore the error is NOT a good idea. Add ... `if (colWiseRecord.Length >= 3) { ...` before you add the row to prevent the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will throw an error and cannot be run. Specify the number of columns for the datagridview, and then load the data into the datagirdview through the foreach loop, so that you can see all the data in the txt document. Here is my code, you could try the following code to replace it.

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream("D://abc.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(f);
            sw.Write(txtregno.Text + "," + txtname.Text + "," + txtmarks.Text + ";");
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
            sw.Close();
        }

        

        private void btnshow_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream f = new FileStream("D://abc.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f);
            string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
            string[] lineWiseRecord = data.Split(';');
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "regno";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Mark%";

            foreach (string item in lineWiseRecord)
            {
                string[] colWiseRecord = item.Split(',');
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(colWiseRecord);
            }
            f.Close();
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Result:

[image]